# Web API - How to set cookie with authen request

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I have built small example with asp.net web api. I create a api for authentication. I try to use set-cookie response header when user logged in successful. But in next request, i can't find cookie in header. Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot!!!

```
        if (repository.CheckValidUser(user))
        {
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();

            var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("Authorization-Token", RSAClass.Encrypt(user.Username));
            cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
            cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
            cookie.Path = "/";

            resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
            return resp;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, Content = new StringContent("Invalid user name or password.") });
        }
```

I have some photos about my request

[image: authen request]

[image: next request]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a DelegatingHanlder to persist cookies, for exemple:

```
public class MyCookieHandle : DelegatingHandler
{
    async protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //
        //  Other code for retrieve user information
        //
        var cookie = request.Headers.GetCookies("Authorization-Token").FirstOrDefault();

        if (cookie == null)
        {
            cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("Authorization-Token", RSAClass.Encrypt(user.Username));
            cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
            cookie.Domain = request.RequestUri.Host;
            cookie.Path = "/";
        }

        HttpResponseMessage resp = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });

        return resp;
    }
}
```

There's more information here: [HTTP Cookies in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-cookies)

Comment: Wow, i will try it. Thank you so much. I waste 2 hours for this problem. Thank you.

Comment: But why i can't use set-cookie header in controller? Can you explain this for me? Thank you!

Comment: You can, but you must persist every cookie for request, or It will be lost, given that you are dealing with Wep API that handle directly HTTP Resquest / Response