# Persistent cookies with Web API

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to set persistent cookies in my Web API (v2), .NET 4.0 application.

Right now, I'm able to append a cookie to the response alright, and used [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-cookies) to do so.

Using Chrome dev. tools, I do see the response with the cookie and its value properly set with the `Set-cookie` header.

The problem is that because I have not implemented the recommandations in "Set and Retrieve Cookies in a Message Handler", when the client sends a request back to the Web API, the cookie is not available when I debug the application.

The issue is that I'm limited to VS2010 (.NET 4.0) due to an SDK I've got to use that supports only VS2010 and the `async` and `await` keywords are, obviously, C# 5.0.

Is there any way I could achieve something like such using .NET 4.0/C# 4.0 ?

EDIT:
My javascript client is running on http://mymachine.domain.ca:1841 while the Web API is running on http://mymachine.domain.ca:24504/api/. I wonder if that is the issue

Actually, `mymachine.domain.ca` is localhost but I can't post that to SO apparently.
Thanks!

Comment: Using chrome debug tools, you are saying that the next request to your Web API endpoint after the cookie has been set does NOT contain the cookie? Because in the tutorial you linked, it says "The previous examples showed how to use cookies from within a Web API controller. **Another** option is to use message handlers." It sounds like it should be working as-is

Comment: @welegan This post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103924/web-api-how-to-set-cookie-with-authen-request) says the bottom part of the tutorial (message handlers) 'should' be used, but yes, I had not caught the "Another" meaning which implies both should work I guess.

Comment: Did you also set the path of the cookie to "/"?

Comment: @Rabi I did that and tried ignoring setting it as well, no go. My javascript client is running on `http://localhost:1841` while the Web API is running on `http://localhost:24504/api/`. I wonder if that is the issue.

Comment: Your port number definitely matters, with regards to cookies. Different port numbers might as well be different domains, so this is really a security issue. You should use CORS to make your development environment work.

Comment: @welegan I have implemented CORS within my solution. So it's probably something about the path.

Comment: Forget it, I'll just have the Web API send the session ID in the response body, have the javascript client lug it around on each request in the parameters.